# How to calculate difference between two rows(strings) in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a following dataframe

```
ClientID          month            test
 ASD               Sep        Auto:2,Finance:1
 ASD               Oct        Finance:2
 FGH               Sep        Auto:1,Finance:2
 FGH               Oct        Oil:2
```

Above dataframe I got from following code

```
df %>% 
  group_by(client_id, month, Sector) %>%
  tally() %>%
  group_by(client_id, month) %>%
  summarise(test = toString(paste(Sector, n, sep=":")))
```

Now, what I want to calculate at client level is,the change in his sectors from sep to oct.Like in sep client was holding 2 instruments from Auto sector but in Oct he has reduced to 1 like wise. Or he has added any new sector which was not present in Sepember month. In the above data ASD has 2 instruments from Auto and 1 instrument from Finance and in Oct he has increased 1 instrument in Finance,but sold 2 instruments from Auto. If he decreased the number of instruments from sep to oct then number should come negative.

Desired output will be

```
ClientID       month          test                  Output
  ASD           Sep      Auto:2,Finance:1.            NA
  ASD           Oct      Finance:2                    Finance:1,Auto:NILL
  FGH           Sep      Auto:1,Finance:2             NA
  FGH           Oct      Oil:2                        Oil:2,Finance:2,Auto:1
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(ClientID = rep(c("ASD.", "DFG."), each = 5),
      month = rep(c("Sep", "Oct" ) , c(3,2)),
      Sector = c("Auto", "Auto", "Finance", "Finance", "Finance", 
      "Auto", "Finance", "Finance", "Oil", "Oil"),
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Can we achieve this in above code?

Comment: Can you use `dput(df)` to make it reproducible please?

Comment: The code for the data doesn't correspond to the data presented above.

Comment: That is just a sample code I gave.

Comment: I meant the data creation part at the end.

Comment: @Sotos  you can use the same code to reproduce data.I have edited the question.